# Quaternion square root

Tags: code-golf, math, complex-numbers

### Background

[Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) is a number system that extends complex numbers. A quaternion has the following form

$$ a + bi + cj + dk $$

where \$ a,b,c,d \$ are real numbers and \$ i,j,k \$ are three *fundamental quaternion units*. The units have the following properties:

$$ i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1 $$
$$ ij = k, jk = i, ki = j $$
$$ ji = -k, kj = -i, ik = -j $$

Note that **quaternion multiplication is not commutative**.

### Task

Given a *non-real* quaternion, compute at least one of its square roots.

#### How?

According to [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382440), we can express any non-real quaternion in the following form:

$$ q = a + b\vec{u} $$

where \$ a,b\$ are real numbers and \$ \vec{u} \$ is the imaginary unit vector in the form \$ xi + yj + zk \$ with \$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \$. Any such \$ \vec{u} \$ has the property \$ \vec{u}^2 = -1 \$, so it can be viewed as the imaginary unit.

Then the square of \$ q \$ looks like this:

$$ q^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + 2ab\vec{u} $$

Inversely, given a quaternion \$ q' = x + y\vec{u} \$, we can find the square root of \$ q' \$ by solving the following equations

$$ x = a^2 - b^2, y = 2ab $$

which is identical to the process of finding the square root of a complex number.

Note that a negative real number has infinitely many quaternion square roots, but **a non-real quaternion has only two square roots**.

### Input and output

Input is a non-real quaternion. You can take it as four real (floating-point) numbers, in any order and structure of your choice. Non-real means that at least one of \$ b,c,d \$ is non-zero.

Output is one or two quaternions which, when squared, are equal to the input.

### Test cases

```
   Input (a, b, c, d)  =>  Output (a, b, c, d) rounded to 6 digits

 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0 =>  0.707107,  0.707107,  0.000000,  0.000000
 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0 =>  1.098684,  0.455090,  0.000000,  0.000000
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0 =>  1.168771, -0.427800,  0.427800,  0.000000
 2.0,  0.0, -2.0, -1.0 =>  1.581139,  0.000000, -0.632456, -0.316228
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0 =>  1.224745,  0.408248,  0.408248,  0.408248
 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4 =>  0.569088,  0.175720,  0.263580,  0.351439
99.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.1 =>  9.949876,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.005025
```

Generated using [this Python script](https://tio.run/##hVFda8IwFH3Pr7iwhybxGq26gYKDfvyLsYc0bWc3G7VWUMZ@e3eT1qGMMSiXe0/OOTm53V/azc7Ouy4vSii5xgwN5mLFwMIaeCYzGIGRhmoucyGlemSQIRiEnAjZxFLvSj6xDA5Oo0dWhu8DtSnaU2PhoJpCbxEyeVBVrd9I9NPlQ8eYy1CfttcUGGGMCaYuzeCjZQRjcompGplQzWWKBMcUMKNDFzb1cOLgxAORTx97pWenHoi8JvFWcX97Wbf8LFbDbcHnaqHC8gvhzyZQ5a6pdcvlWVwdZvcWS/XUC/5o7iyY0cfiSGt8YcCnCCEC1alAGsNf43iA/DzzZ@OZg2/47vPjVDmqcjQ1d2Xh4eWy93RIKNgrozSgobLgo9Du901lW@5WowVCsH4OsH9myaUWQjB4@I9zA3H3h6WH5YzUJD5qW7UXMJvCfHTdNw). Only one of the two correct answers is specified for each test case; the other is all four values negated.

### Scoring & winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest program or function in bytes in each language wins.

Comment: Can we take the quaternion as `a, (b, c, d)`?

Comment: @nwellnhof Sure. Even something like `a,[b,[c,[d]]]` is fine, if you can somehow save bytes with it :)

Answer (score 30):

### [APL (NARS)](http://www.nars2000.org/), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

`√`

NARS has built-in support for quaternions. ¯\_(⍨)_/¯

Comment: I can't help it: you should include " ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ " In your answer

Comment: You dropped this \

Comment: @Barranka Done.

Comment: @Andrew blame it on the Android app... Thank you for picking it up :)

Comment: It'd be better if it's `¯\_(⍨)√¯`

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,c,d):s=((a+(a*a+b*b+c*c+d*d)**.5)*2)**.5;print s/2,b/s,c/s,d/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49DoMwDIXn5hQeE2MCpO0AFSepOuSHqEgIEGHp6VOSdqhUyX7W@/xkeX3tz2VWMbrBg@eaDFlyogs957rgGnVh0BQWbeHQCUR5FajyvK3bOO8QKkWmCmSPdlWIVochQA93BrwmaAgOrQUdtvmz5Rdlr/KuVAn/5FNlW8sUlSkmz0kuGbft52YijWAPxvyywQTjDPmXjp08x0nENw)

More or less a raw formula. I thought I could use list comprehensions to loop over `b,c,d`, but this seems to be longer. Python is really hurt here by a lack of vector operations, in particular scaling and norm.

**[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes**

```python
def f(a,*l):r=a+sum(x*x for x in[a,*l])**.5;return[x/(r*2)**.5for x in[r,*l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDRasMwDHyOv0JvsT3VS9JukIzsR0IevDahhSQtjgseY9@eWco2VkbBCN3pfEh3effH87RdlkPXQy8t6kFVrrYP83WUQQfozw4CnKaGRq3S2jy9uM5f3dSER@l0wdSvypGqXfZ27maooREgM4QcIdZMYYT5P7j5phgXPNsURP/R02OYGZIakpktlR3TZbl6EpMr0QrBB41ehngP7wvpR7Uzef@JcLdJTbxktF7qoH4ciluL0jyvH@40NxaCghliMMCJVCKx@IZ7PNSDSBxHRKEzpURycafJS9p6UAhp/ZriukGUKrV8AQ)

Solving the quadratic directly was also shorter than using Python's complex-number square root to solve it like in the problem statement.

Comment: "Input is a non-real quaternion. You can take it as four real (floating-point) numbers, in any order and structure of your choice." So you can consider it to be a pandas series or numpy array. Series have scaling with simple multiplication, and there are various ways to get norm, such as `(s*s).sum()**.5`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Sqrt
<<Quaternions`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb8z@4sKiEy8YmsDSxJLUoLzM/rzjhf0BRZl6JQ5oDQjDaUM9AR0EBjYz9DwA)

Mathematica has Quaternion built-in too, but is more verbose.

---

<sub>Although built-ins look cool, do upvote solutions that don't use built-ins too! I don't want votes on questions reaching HNQ be skewed.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

Based on the direct formula [used by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176055/58563).

Takes input as an array.

```javascript
q=>q.map(v=>1/q?v/2/q:q=((v+Math.hypot(...q))/2)**.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9LC8IwEITv/RW5dVfb7cMHqKSe9OYvkB5CH7ZFm0ZD0F8fjdqDICxz@GaGZTphxK24toMOe1lWtuZW8UzRRQxgeJZEamuiNFJrxQHM9CB0Q81jkBqISCFGKU4mtEC7OXqMHVkcsCRwGrM8eJPkHwm/dETpOxGmzvktuhtJTK5DLkwzJ/PRWa0@Lxx8xb3co1ped6JoQDCesUL2N3mu6CxPUIPAzz7nGNJy396rEpaI1Mm2Bz9gPiLaJw)

#### How?

Given an array \$q=[a,b,c,d]\$, this computes:

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}}{2}}$$

And returns:

$$\left[x,\frac{b}{2x},\frac{c}{2x},\frac{d}{2x}\right]$$

```javascript
q =>                            // q[] = input array
  q.map(v =>                    // for each value v in q[]:
    1 / q ?                     //   if q is numeric (2nd to 4th iteration):
      v / 2 / q                 //     yield v / 2q
    :                           //   else (1st iteration, with v = a):
      q = (                     //     compute x (as defined above) and store it in q
        (v + Math.hypot(...q))  //     we use Math.hypot(...q) to compute:
        / 2                     //       (q[0]**2 + q[1]**2 + q[2]**2 + q[3]**2) ** 0.5
      ) ** .5                   //     yield x
  )                             // end of map()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

```hs
f(a:l)|r<-a+sqrt(sum$(^2)<$>a:l)=(/sqrt(r*2))<$>r:l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwEETvfsUePCStSTXtRdH@Qb8gWAhFqZiITeyt/546tlAoLAPzZtjduwljZ22MPTOV5S9fC7MPD7@w8HQpuypep2ckDTts2O8UB/OVjTcTukANaZ1nVGS0at5mpIt/J74EVm2JUKC/MgYul@hJlOQRcgIty886gKJtk8SZYVoPOzNfaPbDtFAKQz1tP8U3)

A direct formula. The main trick to express the real part of the output as `r/sqrt(r*2)` to parallel the imaginary part expression, which saves a few bytes over:

**54 bytes**

```hs
f(a:l)|s<-sqrt$2*(a+sqrt(sum$(^2)<$>a:l))=s/2:map(/s)l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dCsIwDIXv9xS56EWr3V/1ZmPzDXyCUiHIhsN2zGXe@e51mYIghEO@k0OSG9K98z7GXmLt1YualB7zIsxO4p47Sc8g5MWoRpw4oVrKTR1wkjkpH69IHUEL1hYaSg2rFk6DLf8p/TqMZpukht1fmIupyDiXcSg7sBzZrarPOjZK55Ik4DCuh9dPzjDNw7iAYIAetp/iGw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
≔Ｘ⊗⁺§θ⁰ＸΣＥθ×ιι·⁵¦·⁵η≧∕ηθ§≔θ⁰⊘ηＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NDoIwEITvPkWP26QS/Dt5InLQgwlRb4RDhYZuUkBoi7593YbEeJnNzjeZqbWc6kGaEDJrse2hGN5qgnzwT6MaKIy3kLlL36gPjIKlXLAlcfcdXOUrmg/slAUUDDknniaH3xVM8@OKckv7DVvtIMcZG0VIsJHogv5HBDtLM9O85sSLCXsHJ2kdjPSHUJZpson92yi7KPuqCuvZfAE) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @xnor's Python answer. Explanation:

```
≔Ｘ⊗⁺§θ⁰ＸΣＥθ×ιι·⁵¦·⁵η
```

Square all of the elements of the input and take the sum, then take the square root. This calculates \$ | x + y\vec{u} | = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 } = \sqrt{ (a^2 - b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2 } = a^2 + b^2 \$. Adding \$ x \$ gives \$ 2a^2 \$ which is then doubled and square rooted to give \$ 2a \$.

```
≧∕ηθ
```

Because \$ y = 2ab \$, calculate \$ b \$ by dividing by \$ 2a \$.

```
§≔θ⁰⊘η
```

Set the first element of the array (i.e. the real part) to half of \$ 2a \$.

```
Ｉθ
```

Cast the values to string and implicitly print.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 84 bytes

```java
(a,b,c,d)->(a=Math.sqrt(2*(a+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b+c*c+d*d))))/2+" "+b/a+" "+c/a+" "+d/a
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176055/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwDIbvPIXFKW3atA27IMTeAC4cqx6cpGNlJWVNQJomnr0LaQuDadpy@OJIv@3fzg5PGO/UWydrNAZWWOnPCUClbdm@oCxhfXkCbGxb6S1IopqjqEvAaAjEGMgxUMHCpZwnDsairSSsQcMSOoKRiJwsiJ8JLldoX5l5by3hIUF6e2KIVISCylBSFarAnYTTKUypSNDfcrhVgt3i0ufgGrs@Q7tTUynYu0lI7zovAIN@DFsaSyBlaQSQeaYjvetRkf2p@GeN@KHSnYLfsmM@qn/1ceWDj8zX4J4zz6fvivn83qNn9uOP/NJ8Qv@NjLHr1jYfxpZ71hwtO7iF2loTzSTBPC0iwDzz5J6zIhhKn7sv)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,c,d)->           // Method with four double parameters and String return-type
  (a=                 //  Change `a` to:
     Math.sqrt(       //   The square root of:
       2*             //    Two times:
         (a+          //     `a` plus,
          Math.sqrt(  //     the square-root of:
            a*a       //      `a`  squared,
            +b*b      //      `b` squared,
            +c*c      //      `c` squared,
            +d*d))))  //      And `d` squared summed together
  /2                  //  Then return this modified `a` divided by 2
  +" "+b/a            //  `b` divided by the modified `a`
  +" "+c/a            //  `c` divided by the modified `a`
  +" "+d/a            //  And `d` divided by the modified `a`, with space delimiters
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
nOtsн+·t©/¦®;š
```

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176055/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/z7/E88Je7UPbSw6t1D@07NA666ML//@PNtAz1DHQMwJiYyA2iQUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/h5nl4gou9ksKjtkkKSvb/8/xLii/s1T60veTQSv1Dyw6tsz668L/O/2gFAz0DHQUFQzBpACNjuaKhQlgk8OvQRdMHkjBCqNU1gilCtwNOQuwwBOswApPGYNIEKGFpiWotmDSMBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
n                 # Square each number in the (implicit) input-list
 O                # Sum them
  t               # Take the square-root of that
   sн+            # Add the first item of the input-list
      ·           # Double it
       t          # Take the square-root of it
        ©         # Store it in the register (without popping)
         /        # Divide each value in the (implicit) input with it
          ¦       # Remove the first item
           ®;     # Push the value from the register again, and halve it
             š    # Prepend it to the list (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
{s=#+Norm@{##},##2}/(2s)^.5&
```

Port of [@xnor's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176055/52210).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEWvMjBQFJOYRF10UckJxH2pEMRiF6nQZjfM2dOOCoIwfPjvPybF/HykmId7LD00UGhucHd5TSkQIitEz/uNn7c3c6rKdRrG3MoA@gx9i9h1UEEIAYisAqdgTcsKyP03/SVS/XvRXuhPlpNmjXhGJHOQOAqt6887AY65LA)

Answer (score 2):

## C# .NET, 88 bytes

```csharp
(a,b,c,d)=>((a=System.Math.Sqrt(2*(a+System.Math.Sqrt(a*a+b*b+c*c+d*d))))/2,b/a,c/a,d/a)
```

Port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176072/52210), but returns a Tuple instead of a String. I thought that would have been shorter, but unfortunately the `Math.Sqrt` require a `System`-import in C# .NET, ending up at 4 bytes longer instead of 10 bytes shorter.. >.>

The lambda declaration looks pretty funny, though:

```csharp
System.Func<double, double, double, double, (double, double, double, double)> f =
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZFNa8MwDIbv/RU62onz5e5S2vQy2GmFQQc7hBwU210DabzF7mCM/vYsMenapnSbwY/AvJJeS8IEQjeqFRUaA0@Nfm1w9zUBMBZtKWD9aazahQ/7Wiyk3heVYnArkt8FdAkbSFuCrGCCSZouCcF0aLBCuw3X740l3CPoX72ih37hFb7whC89SbsTcVZEyER3ZYS0nU9Otj90KWGFZU1o/xmAZ2UsgTiMGUDiGB9J52eK5E/FP2sEo0oXCn7KDvhRfdPHD0c@EleDO04d784Vs9mlR8fEKQ7jUbmEN@x2b4ZtZTngMLthGfe6NrpS4UtTWvVY1opsCGZxzjBLevAe05wOHQ7tNw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 49 bytes

```perl6
{;(*+@^b>>².sum**.5*i).sqrt.&{.re,(@b X/2*.re)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2lpDS9shLsnO7tAmveLSXC0tPVOtTE294sKiEj21ar2iVB0NhySFCH0jLSBbs7b2vzVXcWKlQpqGXrShnp5xrCaQYRCrqZCWX8SloWCgZ6CjoGAIJg1gpKYOUMYQv4wumjxYxgihWtcIpgrDNDgJljHQMwTrMQKTxmDSBCRjaYlqN5g01NT5DwA)

Curried function taking input as `f(b,c,d)(a)`. Returns quaternion as `a,(b,c,d)`.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{;                                             }  # Block returning WhateverCode
     @^b>>².sum**.5     # Compute B of quaternion written as q = a + B*u
                        # (length of vector (b,c,d))
  (*+              *i)  # Complex number a + B*i
                      .sqrt  # Square root of complex number
                           .&{                }  # Return
                              .re,  # Real part of square root
                                  (@b X/2*.re)  # b,c,d divided by 2* real part
```